Why my layer is entire grey
I'm trying to display a COG file dynamically from a blob. The code in JavaScript I'm using is the next one:
import GeoTIFF from 'ol/source/GeoTIFF.js';
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/WebGLTile.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';

const source = new GeoTIFF({
  sources: [
    {
      url: '{URL_cog}',
    },
  ],
});

const riskLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: source,
});


const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [riskLayer],
  view: new View({
    center: [-492893.235, 5113768.328], 
    zoom: 10, 
  }),
});

const cogValue = document.getElementById('cog-value');

map.on('pointermove', event => {
  const data = riskLayer.getData(event.pixel);
  cogValue.innerHTML = data[0];
  console.log("New value");
});

The image I'm using has only one band in grayscale, and for some reason, when I try to display it in the browser, the entire layer where is placed has a value of 127 in each pixel.I try to display the image in Python from the blob and it works, I use this code to display a RGB image and it works too.

What data values do you get if you use normalize: false,?
